# collision detection and normals from rigidbody

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody, normals

Until now I've been developing my player character using a Character Controller, but have since decided to switch to rigidbody due to the controller's limitations. In order for my movement code to run as expected I need to know when the player is colliding with anything, and the normal of the surface it's colliding with. This is easy with a Character Controller, but is there a simple way to do it with a rigidbody?

Here is a stripped down version of the script I'm using for collisions.

```
 // Used in other scripts (Necessary)
    public GameObject ground = null;
    public Vector3 groundNormal;
    public bool onGround;

    // Used internally
    public bool isColliding;
    public float slopeLimit;

    // Character Controller
    public CharacterController controller;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Check if the player is colliding with anything (Character Controller)
        if (controller.collisionFlags == CollisionFlags.None)
        {
            isColliding = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isColliding = true;
        }

        // Check if the player is standing on the ground
        if (isColliding && groundNormal != Vector3.zero)
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            onGround = false;
        }
    }

    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {
        // Check for floor
        if (Vector3.Angle(transform.up, hit.normal) <= slopeLimit)
        {
            // Store floor object data
            ground = hit.gameObject;
            // Store ground surface normal
            groundNormal = Vector3.Normalize(hit.normal);
        }
        else
        {
            // reset variables
            ground = null;
            groundNormal = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
```

`slopeLimit` is a static value. Additionally, getting the ground object isn't actually necessary atm, but I plan on using it later.

Edit: 
Currently I'm using `controller.collisionFlags` to detect when the player is colliding with something and haven't been able to find a similar alternative. Setting the `isColliding` bool to true using `Rigidbody.OnCollisionStay` would be simple, but setting it to false without use of another void function seems difficult. is that possible at all?

Comment: Presumably you tried handling the OnCollisionEnter (or Stay/Exit) message and reading this info out of the Collision structure it passes you? Did you have any particular difficulty getting what you need that way?

Comment: It's getting that collision detection into bool form that I'm having difficulty with, since I couldn't find a function similar enough to 'collisionFlags'. And if there is a funtion to find the normal of the collided surface, I can't find it or figure out the syntax

Comment: `collision.contacts[0].normal`, no? Want to edit your question to describe the bool problem in more detail?

Comment: Unity's site said `collision.contacts` produces garbage data so I avoided using it, but I couldn't figure out the syntax for the linked alternative, `ContactPoint.normal`. I'll try it though. As for the bool problem, yeah I'll do that.

Comment: You can use `collision.GetContact(0).normal` to avoid allocation, if that's what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your is-colliding boolean just by counting collisions entered and exited:

```
int _collisionCount;
public bool IsColliding { get { return _collisionCount > 0; } }

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    _collisionCount++;
}

void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision) {
    _collisionCount--;
}
```

There are lots of solutions to ground checks, but here's one I like to use:

```
public LayerMask groundLayers; // Populate this with which physics layers count as "ground".

bool IsOnGround(out Vector3 groundNormal) {
    groundNormal = Vector3.zero;

    if ( !IsColliding ) return false; // If we're not colliding with anything, we're not grounded.

    // Physics "contacts" can actually have some minor separation, so let's add a margin.
    float margin = Physics.defaultContactOffset;

    // Start your check from a little above the bottom of your capsule.
    // I like to set up my colliders so "foot position" is always transform.position,
    // but your setup may vary. I like to make my ground check radius 1 margin smaller
    // than my capsule radius, to make sure my check never starts already in-contact
    // with an obstacle.
    Vector3 checkOrigin = GetFootPosition() 
                        + new Vector3(0, groundCheckRadius + margin, 0);

    // Check for a collision under our feet.
    if ( Physics.SphereCast(
             checkOrigin,        // Start just above the bottom of our capsule,
             groundCheckRadius,  // with a sphere slightly smaller than our capsule.
             Vector3.down,       // Fire it downwards,
             out RaycastHit hit, // and record what it hits,
             2 * margin,         // going just far enough to catch a touching contact,
             groundLayers        // with anything marked "ground".
    ) == false) return false;    // If we didn't hit anything, we're not grounded.

    if ( Vector3.Angle(transform.up, hit.normal) > slopeLimit)
        return false; // Too steep to stand on!

    // Otherwise, we are grounded. Extract the ground normal and return true.
    groundNormal = hit.normal;
    return true;
}
```